# Bigquery s3 integration

Tags: amazon-s3, google-bigquery

Does BigQuery have a feature to import data from s3?
If not then whats the best alternative path which you can suggest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BigQuery doesn't support direct ingestion of data from S3 buckets. However, it is easy to move data from S3 buckets to Google Cloud Storage using the gsutil command line tool. I would suggest moving the data to Cloud Storage, then ingesting into BigQuery from there.

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil

Comment: Thanks @Michael will definitely look at the Google cloud storage approach at a convenient time