# How can I export data from BigQuery to S3?

Tags: scripting, amazon-s3, google-bigquery

I would like to automatically export the results of a Google BigQuery query to an S3 bucket every night. Does BigQuery support any kind of automated query runs?

This is kind of the reverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666967/bigquery-s3-integration).

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery does not support any automatic scheduling of jobs. You would have to use some other framework to run some script on a schedule to insert the query job.

One such option might be a Google Apps Script time-driven simple trigger. BigQuery is accessible through Google Apps Script, so putting these together should get you the ability to run BigQuery jobs on a schedule.

Google Apps Script Simple Trigger options: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers

BigQuery Google Apps script sample code: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery